# Where does Steam save information on Selected Collections for Non-Steam Games?

Tags: steam, technical-issues

I'm aware Steam stores shortcuts in `shortcuts.vdf`, and I'm aware that this has a section for `tags`. The actual tags are formatted like this:

```
\x010\x00GOG\x00\x011\x00Itch\x00\x08\x08\x08\x08
```

When you edit the collections on Steam, this file gets updated and tags get appended as expected.

However if you manually insert your own tags into this file, such as by writing out your own entry into this file with Bash, or using the [Python VDF library](https://github.com/ValvePython/vdf), Steam will not pick these up as collections. It does not overwrite anything in this file, and adding new collections will append as expected on top of the shortcuts you inserted yourself. Adding to the example above, if I were to add the `Lutris` collection to my Non-Steam Game via the Steam Client, the tags section of `shortcuts.vdf` would then look as follows:

```
\x010\x00GOG\x00\x011\x00Itch\x012\0x00Lutris\x00\x08\x08\x08\x08
```

But Steam would only display `Lutris` in the client, despite the `shortcuts.vdf` containing multiple. Steam will update `shortcuts.vdf` each time you add a new collection to a shortcut, but it appears as though Steam is not reading the collections to display from this file.

For regular Steam games, there is a leveldb file that contains information about which games are in which collections. However, it does not appear that Non-Steam Games are set here. Modifying the collections in Steam does not update any Local Storage files from what I have observed.

My question is: When you select a collection for a Non-Steam Game, where does Steam store that information?

Comment: I discovered that Steam stores information about Collections + other information previously stored in `shortcuts.vdf`, in `localconfig.vdf`, located in the same dir as `shortcuts.vdf` file. I don't have much to add yet because I'm still testing to find more info, but collections are stored under `user-collections` which is an escaped JSON string in this file. This string also stores whether a game is hidden.

Comment: Information about the Steam Overlay and a VR flag is stored under the "Apps" block in this file, with the signed AppID, controlled by `OverlayAppEnable` and `DisableLaunchInVR`. Unlike collections, this is not updated in `shortcuts.vdf`, and the value is ignored. Although if omitted, Steam deems the shortcuts.vdf file invalid, and will erase it, so it must still be included in the shortcut entry, though it can have `\x00` or `\x01`.

The `AllowDesktopConfig` and `OpenVR` fields in `shortcuts.vdf` are still updated by their corresponding Steam Properties settings.

Comment: The way tags are stored in `localconfig.vdf` are under the `user-collections` JSON escaped string, however some collections (very old tags, 5+ years old) will use an encoded format `uc-<encoded>`, whereas newer ones will use `from-tag-tagname`.

I don't know how these strings are encoded, but if this was known. you could figure out which tag format you need to use for `user-collections` by encoding the string, and grepping a LevelDB log file `~/.local/share/Steam/userdata/<id>/7/remote/sharedconfig.vdf` for both `user-collections.<encoded>` and `user-collections.from-tag-<tagname>`.